# Formatted Text via webservice

Tags: json, web-services, formatting, format

I have a webservice, which returns json-objects. Those json objects (among other properties) usually contain some text. This text has to be formatted to display in the clients browser.
The server holds a database with all those texts stored in it. We are currently planning to have about 50.000 texts stored and initially some thousand requests a day.

I was wondering, how I should handle the formatting. Should I store those texts as html and send the html back inside the json objects. In my personal opinion this approach contradicts the idea of a json webservice, which is used so i do not have to send html every time...

As the formatting is limited to some basic stuff (strong, emphazised and maybe three or four more) should I mark them in another way and do the formatting clientside (like on stackoverflow `*foo*` becomes *foo*.

Are there other ways I didn't thought of? What are the advantages and disadvantegs of those approaches?

To clarifiy: Storing the texts in the database and sending them via a json-webservice are unalterable decisions

Are there existing libraries that handle clientside formatting very performant?